# Facebook PHP: Difference between SDK and no-SDK

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

This may seem like a stupid question, but please bear with me.

I've seen Facebook PHP samples that work by calling `https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxx` and examining the response WITHOUT including `require_once` the `facebook.php` file and WITHOUT instantiating a `$facebook` object.

And then I've seen other PHP samples that start by including `require_once` the `facebook.php` file and instantiating a `$facebook` object, and later on use this object INSTEAD of calling `https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxx`.

What's the difference? Are these simply two different methods for achieving the same thing? Which is preferred?

Comment: The Facebook SDK is just a wrapper around those API calls, so you don't have to handle them manually. Internally, both methods are the same.

Comment: As long as you ask - the SDK solution is preferred

Answer (score 2):

If your application require the user to login, using the PHP SDK is easier because it handles all the login steps in one call but if you just want to retrieve public data, both methods are ok.